# How to validate my custom object received in the controller?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core

So I am starting a new project and I am trying to figurate out what would be the best approach to validate my customs objects.

I have this class:

```
public class UserRegistrationDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string InvitationCode { get; set; }
    public Enums.UserRole UserRole { get; set; }
}
```

And I receive it in the body of the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task RegisterUserAsync(UserRegistrationDto user)
```

So when passed to the service layer, I would like to perform the following validations:

```
        if (Name.Length > 35)
            return false;

        if (UserRole == Roles.Administrator && string.IsNullOrEmpty(InvitationCode)) 
        {
            return false;
        }
```

What would be the best approach/design to do this kind of validations?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following read [MVC model validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

- [StringLength] for the one validation
- [Custom attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-attributes) for the joint option

You can find them in the [data annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations?view=net-5.0)